# start mariadb but systemctl status mariadb with failed

Tags: mariadb

I installed mariaDB under the path ‘/app/mysql’;

Since the configuration file could not be found, I created the 'my.cnf' file under the 'etc/mysql' path and copied the content online, my.cnf CODE:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

When I run the command systemctl start mariadb, no error seems to be reported, but systemctl status mariadb says it failed.  Code:

```
[root@iZbp13edmlpcdqu2759ccaZ system]# systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB - database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-10-19 20:31:46 CST; 13s ago
  Process: 115928 ExecStart=/app/mysql/bin/mysql -c /app/mysql (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 115928 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 19 20:31:46 iZbp13edmlpcdqu2759ccaZ systemd[1]: Started MariaDB - database server.
Oct 19 20:31:46 iZbp13edmlpcdqu2759ccaZ systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 19 20:31:46 iZbp13edmlpcdqu2759ccaZ systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

mariadb.service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=MariaDB - database server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=mysql
Group=mysql


# ExecStartPre=/app/mysql/bin/mysql -t -c  /app/mysql

ExecStart=/app/mysql/bin/mysql -c  /app/mysql
ExecStop=/app/mysql/bin/mysql -s stop


PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I hope to start mariadb successfully. How should I modify it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post the text instead! The question editor has a special "code formatting" button for that.

Comment: By the way, reading the error message tells you what's wrong

Comment: (also, it's a bit questionable that you install MariaDB yourself. Why that? does your Linux distro not have a better way of installing it?)

Comment: man systemd.service says that ExecQuit isn't an option in service files

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answering my question. I'm learning Compiling MariaDB From Source.   I just don't understand what this error message means and I don't know how to fix it.  please see the new question with text. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/759358/systemctl-status-mariadb-with-failed

I delete the ExecQuit but still failed.

Comment: The error message means "ExecQuit" is not something that exists in the context of service files.

Comment: I delete that, but still failed. Are there any other errors that I can try to correct?

Comment: if you deleted it and the error message did not change, you didn't delete it. Come on, work with us here: error messages are important, and they change when you address the underlying problem.

Comment: are you really intending to start `mysql` and not `mysqld`?

Comment: Read the error messages. Read the logs, and when all else fails RTFM https://mariadb.com/kb/en/starting-and-stopping-mariadb-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

If you build with `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/app/mariadb ../mariadb-source` (its not mysql which is why I'm using '/app/mariadb') and compile, you'll find the generated systemd file in `/app/mariadb/support-files/systemd/mariadb.service`.

Like the comments suggest, `mysql` is a client connection tool (now named `mariadb`) and inventing options like  `-c  /app/mysql` and `-s stop` won't mangicly make it behave like a service manager.

Even if you want to invent your own, look at the existing version, its service many users and been pretty reliable, and its author (me) wasn't totally mad.